# About driver on ROS

Tags: ros, driver

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone! Thesedays I am thinking of applying ROS on a simple arm we made. I uses a device to connect the motors with my computer. But that device has no driver for ROS. But I found its driver for linux.

So it means I need to re-write a driver on ROS for this device, right? Can I use that driver for linux and simply include it in my ROS code?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199225/about-driver-on-ros/) by [pcler](https://answers.ros.org/users/20519/pcler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2014-12-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Basically yes. That is usually how I do it.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pcler](https://answers.ros.org/users/20519/pcler/) on 2014-12-10**:
Thank you for answering! If I could get the source code of that device's driver for linux, how can I make use of it? Should I create a "bridge" node inside the ROS or something to make use of it?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-12-10**:
Is this a device driver in form of a kernel module or similar OR a driver that is just a program in userland?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-12-10**:
Usually you'd just write a ROS node that is the driver code (user), but instead of whatever interface it currently uses, e.g. text output, you'd send and receive ROS messages.

**Comment by [pcler](https://answers.ros.org/users/20519/pcler/) on 2014-12-11**:
I have asked for more information. Now we got a .o file for linux kernel module driver and multiple .so Dynamic Loaded Library files. And a .h head file is given for using its API in linux. Could you please tell me how to make use of these things on ROS? I am a new guy. Thank you sincerely!!!

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-12-11**:
As a start you must have some kind of user space program (non-ROS) that talks to your hardware. This you have to figure out for yourself. The next step would be to build that same thing with ROS.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-12-11**:
Once you are there identify what interfaces you'd like to have in ROS and just add these as in the basic tutorials.

**Comment by [pcler](https://answers.ros.org/users/20519/pcler/) on 2014-12-13**:
Thank you so much! Now I am looking into it...

**Comment by [pcler](https://answers.ros.org/users/20519/pcler/) on 2014-12-17**:
Could you help me again? I have got a driver for linux and a .so dynamic library in /lib. Now I can run the user-space program thing on linux. And I am changing it into ROS. But there is question that how to include that .so dynamic library by editing CMakeLists? I can use gcc -l to include that .so